# How to change Windows Phone media player loading progress bar color

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I am working on a WP app and using media player from MS Player framework. I want to customize the progress bar comes before playing video. I generated template xaml for it, but there is no such progress bar.

Comment: Something like that is often embedded down a couple levels in a template. Is there documentation anywhere for the media player you speak of?

Comment: I didn't found anywhere only implementation is there.